# Autostart fails to detect default program

Tags: autohotkey, windows-7-x64

Every time my AHK script runs (the Startup folder constains a symlink that points to the file) Windows asks me what program it should use to open the file. Why does this happen?

Comment: Probably because of a bad installation. If your version is oudated, try re-downloading the program from www.AutoHotkey.com and reinstall properly. Alternatively, right-click any .ahk-file in your file system and select "open with..." / "pick standard program" / "always open ahk files with..." and select your C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like AutoHotkey isn't properly installed? Is it possible you didn't use an installer and are using a Stand Alone version?

To fix:
Either Uninstall/Reinstall latest version of Autohotkey from ahkscript.org

or

Open up Explorer, Right click a file with .ahk, select Open with option, choose a default program, navigate to Autohotkey.exe and choose that program select "always use.." option. If that doesn't fix your problem I'll try and help further.

Comment: I have confirmed that the Autohotkey.exe is set as the default for all .ahk files (via your second suggestion). I will try reinstalling and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Just tried reinstalling, didnt fix the problem. Could this have something to do with the fact that I am trying to start the script from a symlink?

Comment: Symlink might not be working, not sure how or why. I start scripts from the Startup folder by using Shortcuts, right click the script and create a shortcut, drag the short cut into the startup folder.